# Cannot find the json via ajax

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, flask

I am trying to implement a simple web using flask. When I tried to read a local json data from python and pass it to the front end. It failed.

My file hierarchy:

```
-app   
    -static
        -data
            predict.json
        scripts.js   
    -templates
        index.html  
    models.py   
    views.py   
    __init__.py 
run.py
```

Related python part:

```
import os
from app import app
@app.route("/test",methods=['GET'])
def get_local_json():
    SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    json_url = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static/data",'predict.json')
    data = json.load(open(json_url))
    return data
```

Related JS part in scripts.js:

```
$SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/test", function (data) { ...}
```

When I run this web on my computer, the console log shows:

> jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict.json 404 (NOT
>   FOUND)

It seems not detect my modification (my first version just reads the data from JS).

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: Your url is `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict.json` and your route `'predict'` without any `'.json'`.

Comment: @vishes_shell yes, that's why I think it didn't detect my modification. the url should correspond to the @app.route(....), shouldn't it?

Comment: I believe it should. But i also believe that this is a bad practice to serve static file in such way.

Comment: @vishes_shell sorry, I didn't quite get it. you mean to read the json from backend and pass it to the front-end? I just used it for a test. I will call a machine learning model in backend later and pass the predict result to front-end.

Comment: If you will make a some pattern for a view's url, e.g. `'/predict_files/<file_name>'`, and then use `file_name` that was passed, then that's ok. But keeping such url, that depend on filename is kinda weird i think, because if you change your file name, then you need to change `app.route()`. I hope you understand what i'm trying to say. BTW, changing `'predict'` to `'predict.json'` in `route` helped?

Comment: @vishes_shell Not work by changing to 'predict.json'. The url '/predict' is not named after the 'predict.json', Er, I changed it to '/test' to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the browser cache the javascript file, so that no matter what modification I made, it just failed to detect it.

To avoid it, a smart way is to add change the js statement in html to href="xxx.js?ver=1.0"